# Angular Update 12 to 13 failing with conflicting peer dependency

Tags: angular

I am trying to update an Angular project from version 12 to 13.
I am following the guidance from the Angular update website
https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-13.0 .

This is the package.json before the upgrade process started

```
...
  "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~12.2.15",
        "@angular/common": "~12.2.15",
        "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.15",
        "@angular/core": "~12.2.15",
        "@angular/forms": "~12.2.15",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.15",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.15",
        "@angular/router": "~12.2.15",
        "astronomy-bundle": "~5.17.8",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
        "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.15",
        "@angular/cli": "~12.2.15",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.15",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
```

The error that stops everything is as follows

```
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.15
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^13.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^13.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@13.2.5 
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.2.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^13.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
```

Here is the package.json, after the upgrade process started:

```
...  
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.5",
    "astronomy-bundle": "~5.17.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "d3": "^6.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8"
    ...
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  }
}
```

The project is within a docker container. The update starts, updates the package.json and then stops with the error message.

I would be very grateful for any help,

Thanks.

Comment: for some miracle. I was doing same thing on yesterday I also get same error any update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the package-lock.json & remove the caret before the version number.
options to work around the problem :
-passing the --force.
-Switch to yarn as a package manager

Comment: removing the package-lock.json was sufficient for me

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of package-lock.json file is not updated with the latest versions of Angular.

I am able to solve this problem by deleting package-lock.json file and running npm install again.

As my project is new, no problem in deleting package-lock.json file be careful while deleting this file it might cause other issues.